# Extract string after complex string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with the regex that will allow me to extract an Exception Message from a long Exception string:

> AddlExc="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error: 3980, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
>
> AddlExc="Trebuchet.TrebuchetDbException: Could not connect to SQL Server database ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I've already managed to extract the Exception Type:

```
(?<=AddlExc=")(?P<exception_type>\b\S*Exception\b)
```

This correctly returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" or "Trebuchet.TrebuchetDbException".

Now I want to extract the message following the first ": ", so everything **after** the exception type until the end of the line.  I've managed to get it to work for the first message, using the following:

```
(?<=AddlExc=")\b\S*Exception\s\S*: (?P<exceptionmessage>.*)
```

And likewise I've managed to separately get it to work for the second message with this:

```
(?<=AddlExc=")\b\S*Exception*: (?P<exceptionmessage>.*)
```

But... I can't find the statement to work for both, obviously the "(0x80131904)" is causing issues with my second attempt - Please help!

Here is my test online: https://regex101.com/r/cK3wD8/1

Thanks to the answers below, this works for both:

```
(?<=AddlExc=\")\b\S*Exception\b.*?:\s(?P<exceptionmessage>.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check for the first `:` following your exception name: `.*?:\s` (or `[^:]*:\s`).

```
(?<=AddlExc=\")(?P<exception_type>\b\S*Exception\b).*?:\s(?P<exceptionmessage>.*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, though it works for the line with the numbers, it doesn't for the other line.  I need regex that works for both lines :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with what works following your answer, I can't set both outputs as i'm actually using them for extracted fields in splunk.

Answer (score 1):

To match/capture both, you could do:

```
(?<=AddlExc=")(?P<exception_type>[^\s:]*)[^:]*:\s*(?P<exceptionmessage>.*)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lH2rD3/1)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, both ended up working, but couldn't accept both answers! :)